# creating Two column layout like widgets in aspx

Tags: aspxgridview

[image]

Hi I have to create a two column page layout with pagination in asp.net. The below image is the sample format. How can this be achieved? Can it be possible through Devexpress? two columns and three rows with separators as shown in image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Devexpress's ASPxDataView and setting ColumnCount="2" resolved the issue